# What is the configuration equivalent to `gg`?

Tags: plugin-system

[`call feedkeys('gg', 'int')`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475187/how-to-start-vim-in-insert-mode-at-end-of-first-line-when-committing-git-changes?noredirect=1#comment868010_475187) seems to work, but what would be the Vim configuration language equivalent?

Comment: What do you mean by "vim configuration language"? Vimscript?

Comment: I've no idea. Which language is `call feedkeys('gg', 'int')`? I'm trying to [configure Vim to go start up at the end of the first line in insert mode when editing Git commits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475187/3645).

Comment: Somewhat related post: [Modify vim-fugitive Gstatus mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50537023/438329)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you mean `ggA`? Anyways, there's no separate language for Vim configuration. Everything is "Vim script":

> Your first experience with Vim scripts is the vimrc file.  Vim reads it when
>   it starts up and executes the commands.  You can set options to values you
>   prefer.  And you can use any colon command in it (commands that start with a
>   ":"; these are sometimes referred to as Ex commands or command-line commands).
>      Syntax files are also Vim scripts.  As are files that set options for a specific file type.

(from [`:h vim-script-intro`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#vim-script-intro))

So the literal answer to your literal question is: `call feedkeys('ggA', 'int')`. A slightly more thoughtful answer would also mention that if you want to execute Normal mode commands from a script (or from the command line) then you typically would use [`:norm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal). E.g. `norm! ggA`. (The `!` is used to prevent interference from existing mappings.)

Note: someone answered your question on the other site with an `autocommand` based solution and I think that's the right approach. Have you followed through on that?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the `autocommand` solution did work; I was just trying to split the problem into manageable pieces to work out a solution.